# Can I change (or add more apps to) the unlock screen in Ice Cream Sandwich?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, lock-screens, motorola-droid-razr

On the previous version I could swipe left or right to start with my camera, or just unlock the phone. I just got the Ice Cream Sandwich update and now I can swipe up or down to access the dialer or my text messages. Can I customize this at all? I'd love to have more apps accessible from the lock screen, and I'd also like to change from the default text message program.

Comment: Depends entirely on what ROM your are running, it's not a feature that's usually available in stock ROMs as far as I know. If the feature is not there under settings, you just need to find a ROM for your phone that has that feature.

Comment: Cyanogenmod 9 has this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [WidgetLocker Locksscreen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker). Using it, you can put high no. of apps on lockscreen.

Comment: Do you need root for this app? I couldn't find confirmation either way.

Comment: @aslum No.. the app doesn't need root access at all..

Answer (score 1):

For the One Plus One Phone running Android Version 4.4.4 with CyanogenMod version 11.0-XNPH44S, go to Settings -> Lock Screen -> Slider Shortcuts.

You will just see the icon of the lock and after you touch it, you will see your current options. To change or remove one of these, move the lock to the target icon and you will then see options to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Settings-> Security-> Lock Screen Options-> Shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

On the stock Verizon HTC Thunderbolt that just got the ICS update, you can access this capability by:

- choosing the Personalize "paint palette" icon on the bottom of the home screen
- choosing `display` from the bottom toolbar
- selecting `Lock Screen shortcuts`.

Answer (score -2):

It can be done in ICS.

1. Go to Security under settings.
2. Go into Screen Security Go into
3. Shortcut Settings ... voila!

Comment: -1: I'm using ICS and I don't see this option. Under Screen Security I have three options **Screen Lock**, **Owner Info** and **Allow Bluetooth Bypass**. You got my hopes up. ):

Comment: @bluecjh It might be useful to mention on what device/ROM the settings can be found here.